# How to control notification light flash/on/off

Tags: android

There's this blue light that flashes on the phone to notify the user of something.

How do I control it and how do I make it on/off/flash?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Notification Manager to start the lights blinking in a particular pattern.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

  int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
  int LED_ON_MS = 100;
  int LED_OFF_MS = 100;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     flash();
  }

  void flash() {
     NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     Notification notif = new Notification();
     notif.ledARGB = Color.BLUE;
     notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
     notif.ledOnMS = LED_ON_MS;
     notif.ledOffMS = LED_OFF_MS;
     nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);

  void clearLED() {
     NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     nm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     clearLED();
  }

}
```

Comment: It seems like the light will only flash when the screen is off. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

When buiding a notification, you can use the [setLights()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLights(int,%20int,%20int)) method to customize your lights.

If you just want to use the default settings, use [setDefaults()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDefaults(int))